# youtube-iframe-api embedd parameters is not working anymore

Tags: parameters, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to embed a youtube video on my website with the following parameters, but it is not working:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1xPEIXk69lc?rel=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1"  frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the parameters have been deprecated as of Sept-Oct of 2018 including showinfo and a change to rel=0.  Removing them helps. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters for additional information.
If you work with the IFrame API, (as opposed to embedding an iframe ex http://youtu.be/?videoIDxxx...) you can get the event for the stopping (completing) of the video, then cue up the video by ID into the player.    See https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls for reference to the basic player.

```js
 

....
<div id="player1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player ;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
    {
    player = new YT.Player('player1', 
        { 
        videoId: 'YourVideoId',
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
             }
        });

    }; // onYOuTubeIframeAPIReady
      
function onPlayerStateChange(event)
    { 
    // Alt approach //if( event.data  == 0){ location.reload()}
    if( event.data  == 0)  // video has ended
        { player.cueVideoById({videoId:'YourVideoID',
                               suggestedQuality: 'hd720'})
        };
    } 

     </script>
```